manifest.mpd m3u lists not playing in MacOS/VLC
What's the best player for MacOS to play m3u lists containing manifest.mpd elements?
I'm trying with VLC 3.0.20, but it says that MRL cannot be played with the URL containing the manifest.mpd
Is there any media player recomended to do so? different than Kodi
